# Singleton Bottleneck in Parallel Computing

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing

Every similar question has received answers about thread safety. I am NOT asking about thread safety. Please, DO NOT mistake this for a question about data consistency in concurrent programs.

Question: If you have 1000 threads, running on 1000 CPU cores, which all call the same stateless method on a SINGLETON object, will a performance bottleneck result from the fact that there is only 1 copy of that method in memory?

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, and Sometimes not.   Since you don't have to worry about thread safety, then your global variable is only either accessed read-only, or it uses some form of busy-waiting to synchronize updates.

In the read-only case, there is no issue; many cores will have bits in their caches, but that doesn't induce a bottleneck in its own right; it is just normal traffic.

In the case of busy-waiting, there is an issue; contention and update will cause a flurry of bus invalidation cycles, which can substantively slow down the operation.

If global variables are considered bad in normal practice, they might be considered very bad in massively parallel programs.